# Creating list from list in python based on an if condition

Tags: python, list

I want to create a new_list which will contain only the items of my old_list which satisfy the condition that the index in an array of labels is 3. I am trying something like this:

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if idx[x] == 3]
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

But i am getting the following error because idx is an array. How can i solve this problem?

edited: Idx is an array of equal size with my original data which contains labels for them. So basically i want to create a new list  which will contain only the items of my original list which e.g have the label 3.

I want to do something like this:
cluster_a = [old_list[x] for x in idx if x == 3]

Clarification: my old list is a list containing 3d arrays and the idx is an equal size array containing a label for each 3d array of my list as i aforementioned. I am trying my best to explain the problem. If something is needed please tell me.

[image: This is the list with the 3d arrays]

[image: and this is the array with the labels]

Comment: what you mean by *index in an array of labels is 3* ? what index ? can you show an example ?

Comment: i mean the containing value

Comment: Can you show us what `old_list` looks like?

Comment: And why do you have to do it with list comprehension? By making it 3 lines longer this will become a very easy task, and at the same time code readability will skyrocket.

Comment: Code readability will probably not be an issue if the correct code is written.

Comment: now can you change your explain based on this pictures ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that `idx` is a list but probably that `x` is an array - `old_list` must contain a list as an element. You need to reference the index, and not the item itself:

```
[old_list[x] for x in range(len(old_list)) if idx[x] == 3]
```

here's a minimal example:

```
>>> old_list = [4,5,6]
>>> idx = [3,2,3]
>>> [old_list[x] for x in range(len(old_list)) if idx[x] == 3]
[4, 6]
```

Comment: This identifies the (likely) problem, but does not provide a solution.

Comment: The solution in this case is to rethink the logic. Its impossible to tell what can be done differently with the code exposed.

Comment: Which is why you need clarification of the actual problem before providing an answer.

Comment: @WeaselFox which would mean that, currently, there is no possible answer and we should probably flag the question appropriately and/or ask in comments. But this isn't really an answer.

Comment: @Puciek - I dont agree, but in any case the question was updated, so that irrelevant.

Comment: If i want to do it iteratively for different values besides the value 3 in order to obtain many new lists based on different index references, do you have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: To make it more clear, in your example, if i wanted iteratively to create also a new list for idx[x] == 2 and in general for many different values,  can can that be done?

Comment: Yes but the name of the new_list will be the same and overwritten. e.g in Matlab there is the function eval() that iteratively can change the name of a variable

Comment: This is a basic programming question.. It can be done iteratively and stored in a list of lists, its pretty standard. I suggest asking a new question...

Answer (score 0):

What about this ? :

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if idx.index(x) == 3 ]
```

Comment: when i try that i get an AttributeError:'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: `idx.index(x)` will return the first index in idx where the value is x, but according to the OP, idx is a list of labels, so I dont think this is right.